# How to regenerate values in AutoSeededX917RNG

Tags: c++, random, crypto++

I need to regenerate the pseuorandom values when I need them. My code is:

```
static const unsigned int BLOCKSIZE = 5; 
byte scratch[ BLOCKSIZE ];

CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG<CryptoPP::AES> rng;
rng.GenerateBlock(scratch,BLOCKSIZE);

std::cout << "The generated random block is:" << std::endl;
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < BLOCKSIZE; i++ )
{
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>( scratch[ i ] );
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Why did you post that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to regenerate values in AutoSeededX917RNG

You can't because you are using an `AutoSeeded*` generator.

### -----

> I need to regenerate the pseuorandom values when I need them...

In that case, I think you only have two choices - an `LC_RNG` (which is insecure) or an `RandomPool` (more secure, but it has gaps). Both would require you to operate the generator ***with*** the same seed to produce the same bit streams.

`RandomPool` is a PGP style generator and its underlying algorithm is `MDC<SHA>`. <strike>It will produce the same stream of bits given the same seed.</strike> It uses time, so it produces a different stream for each run (even with the same seeds).

Do ***not*** use an `AutoSeeded*` generator, like `AutoSeededRandomPool` or `AutoSeededX917RNG`. The `AutoSeeded*` read from the OS's entropy pool and then seed the generators with the bits it read.

Also see [RandomNumberGenerator](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator) on the Crypto++ wiki.

### -----

**UPDATE**: `RandomPool` uses time (sorry, I should have checked before I recommended it).

You *can* use `OFB_Mode<T>::Encryption` to generate reproducible random streams. The Crypto++ test program uses it (see `test.cpp` - its the generator returned from `GlobalRNG()`). An example is shown below.

```
SecByteBlock seed(32 + 16);
OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, seed, seed.size());

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption prng;
    prng.SetKeyWithIV(seed, 32, seed + 32, 16);

    SecByteBlock t(16);
    prng.GenerateBlock(t, t.size());

    string s;
    HexEncoder hex(new StringSink(s));

    hex.Put(t, t.size());
    hex.MessageEnd();

    cout << "Random: " << s << endl;
}
```

[`OFB_mode<T>::Encryption`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_o_f_b___mode.html) can be used as a generator because OFB mode uses [`AdditiveCipherTemplate<T>`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_additive_cipher_template.html), which derives from `RandomNumberGenerator`.

Running it produces similar to below.

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
```

### -----

You can also use the code below in `AES_RNG.h` for a deterministic generator based on AES-256. It will produce the same bit stream if presented with the same seed. Its a little more flexible than `OFB_Mode<T>::Encryption` because it can take a arbitrarily-sized seed.

The code to test it is as follows:

```
SecByteBlock seed(32);
OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, seed, seed.size());

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    AES_RNG prng(seed, seed.size());

    SecByteBlock t(16);
    prng.GenerateBlock(t, t.size());

    string s;
    HexEncoder hex(new StringSink(s));

    hex.Put(t, t.size());
    hex.MessageEnd();

    cout << "Random: " << s << endl << endl;
}
```

Its output will look similar to below. Each run of the program will be different because each run uses a different seed (by way of `OS_GenerateRandomBlock`):

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe 
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
Random: D9B48CB7D37C88BDF2A0B0022AB1A812
```

**AES_RNG.h**:

```
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
using CryptoPP::NotCopyable;
using CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation;
using CryptoPP::BlockCipher;

#include <cryptopp/secblock.h>
using CryptoPP::AlignedSecByteBlock;
using CryptoPP::FixedSizeSecBlock;

#include <cryptopp/smartptr.h>
using CryptoPP::member_ptr;

#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
using CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock;
using CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator;

#include <cryptopp/aes.h>
using CryptoPP::AES;

#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
using CryptoPP::SHA512;

class AES_RNG : public RandomNumberGenerator, public NotCopyable
{
public:
    explicit AES_RNG(const byte *seed = NULL, size_t length = 0)
    : m_pCipher(new AES::Encryption), m_keyed(SeedHelper(seed, length))
    {
    }

    bool CanIncorporateEntropy() const
    {
        return true;
    }

    void IncorporateEntropy(const byte *input, size_t length)
    {
        m_keyed = SeedHelper(input, length, false);
    }

    void GenerateIntoBufferedTransformation(BufferedTransformation &target, const std::string &channel, lword size)
    {
        if (!m_keyed) {
            m_pCipher->SetKey(m_key, m_key.size());
            m_keyed = true;
        }

        while (size > 0)
        {
            m_pCipher->ProcessBlock(m_seed);
            size_t len = std::min((size_t)16, (size_t)size);
            target.ChannelPut(channel, m_seed, len);
            size -= len;
        }
    }

protected:
    // Sets up to use the cipher. Its a helper to allow a throw
    //   in the contructor during initialization.  Returns true
    //   if the cipher was keyed, and false if it was not.
    bool SeedHelper(const byte* input, size_t length, bool ctor = true)
    {
        // 32-byte key, 16-byte seed
        AlignedSecByteBlock seed(32 + 16);
        SHA512 hash;

        if(ctor)
        {
            memset(m_key, 0x00, m_key.size());
            memset(m_seed, 0x00, m_seed.size());
        }

        if(input && length)
        {
            // Use the user supplied seed.
            hash.Update(input, length);
        }
        else
        {
            // No seed or size. Use the OS to gather entropy.
            OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, seed, seed.size());
            hash.Update(seed, seed.size());
        }

        hash.Update(m_key.data(), m_key.size());
        hash.TruncatedFinal(seed.data(), seed.size());

        memcpy(m_key.data(), seed.data() + 0, 32);
        memcpy(m_seed.data(), seed.data() + 32, 16);

        // Return false. This allows the constructor to complete
        //   before the pointer m_pCipher is used.
        return false;
    }

private: 
    FixedSizeSecBlock<byte, 32> m_key;
    FixedSizeSecBlock<byte, 16> m_seed;    
    member_ptr<BlockCipher> m_pCipher;
    bool m_keyed;
};
```

Comment: 5 years later, Thank you!